# Oracle DB french character are replacing with junk values when inserting using fluent Nhibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent Nhibernate to manage database activities. When i try to insert french character in Oracle DB using fluent Nhibernate, some of the characters are replaced by junk values.

eg:- "général" converted to "general" or "g?n?ral"

The datatype of column is `NVARCHAR2`.

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET=US7ASCII

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=AL16UTF16.
```

Below query is inserting correct value when I execute it directly in plsql.

```
update table_name set test_col=N'général' where id='1';
```

1. How can I execute this query in fluent Nhibernate in C#?
2. Is there any other solution to insert special french character in Oracle database?

Comment: Which provider do you use for Oracle Connection?

Comment: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.

Comment: Are you sure about `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`? Then you should not have this problem. Also my advise for `NLS_LANG` would not have any effect, see [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featGlobal.htm#ODPNT437)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the ODP.NET provider (`OracleDataClientDriver : Oracle.DataAccess`). In this case, what is the value of your `NLS_LANG` environment variable?

Most likely it is not defined and Oracle defaults it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII`.
However `US7ASCII` does not support any accent characters. Use a character set which support them, e.g. `AL32UTF8` or `WE8ISO8859P1` or `WE8MSWIN1252`, etc.

In case you use the `NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver` driver, you should change to one of the other ones since base `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) for ages.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I feel your suggestion will work for me. I have searched about the character set migration. I could see there may have some difficulties when migrating from one character set to another. Like truncating the data and authentication issues etc. Do you think it is fine to migrate from US7ASCII to AL32UTF8 or WE8ISO8859P1 or WE8MSWIN1252.

Comment: From `US7ASCII` you can migrate to anything without data loss. However, as your data type is `NVARCHAR2` the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`applies. `AL16UTF16` is the most common character set for `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`, so most probably this would not change anyway.